# main.py: cannot connect to X server

Tags: ubuntu, python-2.7, interfaz-gráfica, windows10, pyqt4

Estoy intentando ejecutar una aplicación en Python desde la consola integrada de ubuntu 18.04 que trae Windows 10, ya instale todas las librerías necesarias de pyqt4 pero el error continua

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64
¿Kernel: 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
¿Uptime: 3 hours, 7 mins
Packages: 885
Shell: bash 4.4.20
Terminal: /dev/tty1
CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 2.592GHz
Memory: 15064MiB / 16303MiB
```

Código:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from CfrmBackupsConfig import CfrmBackupsConfig


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    form = CfrmBackupsConfig()
    form.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Intenta lo siguiente: xhost local:root

Comment: Me muestra lo siguiente : **xhost:  unable to open display ""**

Comment: ¿ Esta corriendo xserver en tu computadora cuando haces esa prueba ?

Comment: No, como hago eso? Tiene que ser sobre windows, cierto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cannot connect to X server, la consola de Ubuntu 18.04 en Windows 10 no te da el servidor gráfico necesario para poder correr pyqt4, es por ello que instale un servidor sobre mi Windows: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ y con ello el problema quedo resuelto

[image: Sistema funcionando con servidor Xming]